# Process authentication for Linux

Tags: linux, malware, virus

Is there any possibility to authenticate a running process in Linux to be sure that this is the original/right one?

I know that an Linux operating system is only that secure like the way you use it. For Example: *Lets say I'm using Ubuntu Linux and install any software via a PPA, that software get rights to do everything it want's in my system, because I have to install it with sudo rights.* (PPA's are in general a security problem in Ubuntu I think)

Let us assume the "bad guy coded software" installs the things to do the work I expected, e.g a Gnome-Theme, a dynamic wallpaper whatever. **But also it replaces any process of my Ubuntu system with a key-logger or any other kind of malware and runs in my system.**

Is there any chance to check a running process in Linux if it is the original one?

The running processes are easy to get/find out and the processes of the OS and also the processes from a Ubuntu apt repository are known, so I guess there could be a **possibility to compare the code of the running processes with any database of known Ubuntu repository software/processes and known Linux software/processes.**

Is some kind of process authentication possible or available for Linux/Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can know whether a file has been modified by checking a secure hash of it's contents. You can do this manually, or you can use your package manager; with RPM it's `rpm -V`, with apt you use `debsums`.

Then it's a matter of checking to see if the process was started using that file. That bit's simple as well: check the `proc` entry. This keeps track not only of the path to the file, but also its inode number, so if the file is replaced, it will not match. Observe:

```
[tylerl@tyler-11 ~]$ ./foo &
[1] 26157
[tylerl@tyler-11 ~]$ ls -l /proc/26157/exe 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 tylerl tylerl 0 2013-01-16 12:31 /proc/26157/exe -> /home/tylerl/foo
[tylerl@tyler-11 ~]$ ls -l /home/tylerl/foo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tylerl tylerl 8.3K 2013-01-16 12:31 /home/tylerl/foo
[tylerl@tyler-11 ~]$ echo 1 >> foo
-bash: foo: Text file busy
[tylerl@tyler-11 ~]$ rm foo
rm: remove regular file `foo'? y
[tylerl@tyler-11 ~]$ echo 1 > foo
[tylerl@tyler-11 ~]$ ls -l /proc/26157/exe 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 tylerl tylerl 0 2013-01-16 12:31 /proc/26157/exe -> /home/tylerl/foo (deleted)
[tylerl@tyler-11 ~]$ ls -l /home/tylerl/foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 tylerl tylerl 2 2013-01-16 12:32 /home/tylerl/foo
```

Note two things: (a) the file can't be modified while it's running, and (b) while you can delete it and replace it, the new directory entry will correspond to a *different* executable, and the proc entry will say `(deleted)` to warn you of the difference.

Note that I could recover the original file just by running `cp /proc/26157/exe ./orig_exe`, and then I could examine it as necessary. Files aren't actually deleted from disk until the last reference is closed.

Comment: This is really helpful. The rpm - V (debsums for apt) are very nice tools. To check the file from which the process is started is a good point too. thx! =)

Comment: Don't forget the libraries, see /proc/PID/maps for those. Related to that, there's another potential problem: code injection (not the input validation kind), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378158/code-injection-solaris-linux and for further reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732927/signed-executables-under-linux

Answer (score 0):

debsums can help but it's not the final answer.

For example a package could install an entirely new file in /usr/local/sbin, and then go through the .profile files of the users it finds and add a line to execute that process.

debsums would not complain, no file belonging to a packet has been altered.
Also, files on /etc are installed by packages but are meant to be altered. But there is really no need to tamper with other packages do something nasty.

For example a package could install a service, the configuration step would configure that script to run at boot time, with root privileges. There is absolutely no need to modify existing binaries, except maybe that it could be a bit more obvious to spot.